# Solution to Nonlinear, Autonomous ODE with square root?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have been unable to solve the following equation:

$y'= \sqrt{1-y^2}$, $\:\:y(0)=-1$

I have tried z-substitution to no avail, and was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how I should go about solving this. I do know that the final answer is non-unique:

$y=1$ and $y=-\cos(x)$.

Thank you!

Comment: I meant to say the solution included y=-1 and y=-cos(x). Thanks for catching that Kobe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have $y = 1$ as a solution because it does not satisfy the initial condition $y(0) = -1$.

Your equation is separable: we can write

$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1 - y^2}} = dx$$

and integrate both sides to get

$$\arcsin(y) = x + C$$

where $C$ is a constant. Invoking the initial condition $y(0) = -1$, we obtain $-\pi/2 = C$. Therefore $y = \sin(x - \pi/2) = -\cos x$.

Comment: nice! Easy and clean.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we will get $$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} = dt \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} = t + c, c \in \mathbb{R} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$ \arcsin (y) = t + c \Leftrightarrow y(t) = \sin(t + c).$$
But then, $y(0) = -1 \Rightarrow -1 = y(0) = \sin c$ and then, $c = \arcsin (-1)$.
So, $c =\frac{3\pi}{2} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}.$
Then, $$y(t) = \sin (t +\frac{3\pi}{2} + 2k\pi)  $$